# jQuery library code

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, dom

In an attempt to learn JS OOP I am viewing the source code of jQuery to better understand how they do things.  My question may seem simple, but I'm having trouble understanding the reasoning behind several variables that jQuery has defined at the top of their library.  The code is shown below.

```
(function( window, undefined ) {

// Use the correct document accordingly with window argument (sandbox)
var document = window.document,
    navigator = window.navigator,
    location = window.location;

....rest of code

What I don't understand is why they created variables for the document, navigator, and location objects.  Does this resolve some type of browser bug?  I don't understand the benefit of doing this.
```

Comment: its just my humble opinion, but if you really want to learn JS OOP (with clean, readable and well maintainable code), then dont learn it from jQuery. In my Point of view the code is a maze. if you want to learn from a (in my point of view) good structured library then try prototype or others. Edit: its just my opinion

Comment: I'm currently looking at jQuery and YUI.  How is prototype better to learn from any other library, like jQuery?

Comment: i guess thats a matter of taste. i like features like inheritance provided by prototype and prototype.js is more easy to read (for me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're doing that so that, if some other script has mistakenly (or intentionally) created variables called `document`, `navigator`, or `location`, they won't affect jQuery's use of those variables.

Comment: so your saying that it does the same thing as undefined does in the parameters.  k, ty